# Autogenerated REST endpoint from Hibernate?

Tags: rest, jpa, entity

I have a very simple service project (SpringBootApplication) that exposes a REST endpoint via a Spring Boot controller class. The controller maps an /events endpoint that converts a simple incoming event DTO into a slightly different event entity object that is then persisted in a database via a org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository instance.

In my controller, I am only mapping the POST operator because I don't want my clients to be able to GET, PUT or DELETE data from the service.

During a security scan today, I discovered that the service is exposing a /eventsEntities endpoint, which appears to be mapping all of the CrudRepository verbs into the REST endpoint.

Any idea how I managed to enable this automatic endpoint and more importantly, how to disable it?  I'm using Spring Boot 1.2.2.

Answer (score 4):

After some additional digging, I realized that I had inadvertently included org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest in my compile dependencies.  That starter includes spring-data-rest-webmvc, which exposes JPA data over REST.  Removing that dependency resolved the issue.

Hope my realization helps someone else in the future.